# Async.foreach iteration to stop forcely until first iteration executes

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach, sequelize.js

```
    async.forEach(vsr.vehicles, function(vsr_vehicle, callback){
     pjCustom.vehicleJson(vsr_vehicle, function(vehicleInitialize){
     Vehicle.find({ where: { vehicleID: (vsr_vehicle.vehicleID).toString().trim() } }).success(function(vehicleFound){ 
      if(vehicleFound){ 
        //Code Logic is working fine.
       }else{
         vehicleBuild.save().success(function(vehicleNew){  // To create new vehicle of updated vsr
            var vehicleBuild = Vehicle.build(vehicleInitialize)
              pj.log("Update vehicle ............................")
              temp.push(vehicleNew.vehicleID)  
          })
      }
    })
})   
 callback()
  },function(){
res.send(204)
})


    //vehicleJSON
    exports.vehicleJson = function(vsr_vehicle, callback){ 
          pjCustom.getVehicle(vsr_vehicle, function(status, vehicleId){
    if (status == true) {
  vsr_vehicle.vehicleID = vehicleId
      callback(
      { 'vehicleID':vsr_vehicle.vehicleID).toString().trim(),'vsr_id':vsr_vehicle.vsr_id})
      }
    })
  }


     //getvehicle 

      exports.getVehicle = function(vsr_vehicle, callback){
      if(vsr_vehicle.vehicleID !== undefined){
       callback(true, vsr_vehicle.vehicleID)
        }else{
         Vehicle.find({ where: { 'vsr_id': vsr_vehicle.vsr_id }, 
             attributes: ['id',  'vehicleID'],'order': 'id DESC', 'limit': '1'             
     }).success(function(vehicles){
  var temp = (vehicles.vehicleID).split("-")
  var newvehicleId = temp[0]+"-"+temp[1]+"-"+(parseInt(temp[2])+1)
  callback(true, newvehicleId)
        })
   }
  }
```

Explanation:

while inserting a record from vsr_vehicle. I need to check whether the vehicleID is present then it will fetch if not it will creates a new Id.
    Consider this code is for updating a vehicle as well as inserting another "two" new vehicles. how to manage async process. of insertion of new vehicles.
it is not waiting for completion of first iteration and going for vehicleJson and generating same vehicleID for both new vehicles. suggest me to complete this challange.

My Code is clearly written here.

Please requesting before reading pls copy the code and paste in any JS editor you definitely will understand more than my explanation.

Comment: Suggestions to Complete the above task. I have multiple tasks in line. but still i was running around this task from long period. help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback call in series.forEach is at the incorrect place.  Here is the correction:

```
async.forEach(vsr.vehicles, function(vsr_vehicle, callback){
    pjCustom.vehicleJson(vsr_vehicle, function(vehicleInitialize){
        Vehicle.find({ where: { vehicleID: (vsr_vehicle.vehicleID).toString().trim() } }).success(function(vehicleFound){
            if(vehicleFound){
                callback();  // <--- call here                
            }else{
                vehicleBuild.save().success(function(vehicleNew){  // To create new vehicle of updated vsr
                    var vehicleBuild = Vehicle.build(vehicleInitialize);
                    pj.log("Update vehicle ............................");
                    temp.push(vehicleNew.vehicleID);
                    callback(); // <--- call here
                });
            }
        });
    });
    // callback();     // <--- Don't call here
},function(){
    res.send(204);
});
```

BTW, for good practice, use semicolon (";") at the end of javascript statements

Comment: I'm just listing the correct way of using series.forEach()... there might be errors from Vehicle.find() and vehicleBuild.save()... from the code above, it's hard to tell what they are, their syntax and etc

Comment: There are no logical errors. its executing perfectly but async way. I want to regulate that async process at else condition.

Comment: Can you clarify "else condition"?  or maybe explain what you'd like to do maybe I can find a better approach...

Comment: In the above code if(vehicleFound) { updating a record }else{ inserting a record } my concern to the next of async foreach i preparing vehicleJson. and if it is else condition it is coming inside and inserting. upto now it is ok of insertion. But while inserting i am calling getvehicle to generate a vehicleID at vehicleJSON.  it should not get inserted same vehicleID. for the records which are inserted newly.  Apolosize my english.

Comment: While inserting new vehicles i am looping async so it is inserting same vehicleID generated in getvehicle method. when vehicleJson being called.

Comment: I think you might want to use async.eachSeries() instead of async.forEach().  eachSeries() guarantees that one item is processed at a time.  So in this case, the insert of the first vehicle is done before it starts processing the 2nd vehicle.

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience Ben. Thats what i needed. It is working fine.

Comment: I'm glad that helps and +1 for trying to explain your real issue.